# How to remove localStorage key of different domain?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to remove the localStorage key of different domain in one browser by using JavaScript?
For example I am in the situation of having 2 opened tabs in chrome browser.
And each tab is responsible for showing different domain website.
Can I remove the localStorage key of the other website using JavaScript?
Thanks!

Comment: no - that would be insecure if you could, since if you could delete it, you could read it and write it

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer! so you mean that is completely impossible thing?

Comment: read my comment again if you have any doubts

Comment: LocalStorage interface is restricted to origin. Web content's origin is defined by the scheme (protocol), hostname (domain), and port of the URL used to access it. 

Read more: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage